# CakePHP and validation of multiple forms on same page

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp

I'm building a site in CakePHP and I would like the signup form and the login form to be on the same page thus both using the same controller and model.

So, I've made two new models called UserLoginForm and UserRegisterForm extending the User model and put validation for each form in the models.

The problem is that CakePHP wants me to use form input names that matches the database field name for where the data should go, so for instance, the Email field in the login form has the same name as the Email field in the signup form, causing the validation errors to show up on both forms.. I'm quite new in Cake, so I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to get around this problem.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You should try to think about the model as a record in the matching table, and the controller as the requester of the actions.

In this particular case:

```
├── Controller/
│   ├── UsersController.php
└── Model/
    ├── User.php
```

[The Controller is named after the main model they handle](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html), and as any other thing in cake, this can be changed, but its better avoid it for the sake of readability and latter maintenance.

The validation for both forms should be in the `User` model, since both of them work over a register in the `users` table. Most likely in a [callback method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html).

Since you need a custom validation for each form, you should read ["Dynamically change validation rules"](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#dynamically-change-validation-rules), from the data validation section in the book.

If this gets confusing, try to take a step back and start by [reading this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html) and doing [the blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html).

Once this concepts settle, you will love CakePHP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, David! However, will this work when the fieldnames in the two forms collide? I have been following this tutorial, but it just doesn't work right when the names in the two forms are the same: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/RabidFire/2010/06/26/multiple-forms-per-page-for-the-same-model

Comment: You can do it in multiple ways, one of them could be using a controller action for each form, so you can separate the logic. You can also use the difference in fields between each form to determine what kind of validation should be used.

Comment: I am using a different controller action for each form. Signup form posts to register() method and login to login(). The fields are generated by the formhelper, so they're pretty much the same. I'm missing a feature to remap fields to another database table, however, I found this: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/dardosordi/2008/07/29/multivalidatablebehavior-using-many-validation-rulesets-per-model - Will this work and would it be good practice?

Comment: Remaping should be reserved to really special cases, not for this particular problem. If each form uses a different method in the controller, you just need to validate from the controller, its clearer and closer to the conventions.

Comment: Sorry for asking a perhaps stupid question, but how would I make it differentiate the validation from the controller? Right now, I just do if ($this->User->validates()) { Processing form } { Set flash } and it still shows errors on both forms due to the input names being the same.

Comment: [Dynamically changing the validation rules](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#dynamically-change-validation-rules)

Comment: Yes, I see that. But the problem is, the email field in the login form has the same name as the one in the signup form, thus CakePHP is showing an error on both of the fields, even if it's only the one in the signup form that has been validated as invalid..

Comment: I'm not following, from where I see it, the duplicate field names don't matter since there are different forms pointing to different actions. 

Maybe if you show us your code?

Comment: OK, I just tried it, and it still shows errors on both forms. I've set the validation from the controller method like this: http://pastebin.com/D0vPXSFz - Only the signup email is validated, but errors are shown on both forms...

Comment: Signup form: http://pastebin.com/SV6BKcqL Login form: http://pastebin.com/A7QhPTh2